# Change the slicer state on clicking a button

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have 4 buttons that indicate different ranges and a slicer in my report. I want to change the slicer value according to the button I click.

Is it possible to change the value of the slicer on clicking the button?

Comment: Create a bookmark for each of the values and [assign them to buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks#assign-bookmarks-to-buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Power BI by applying bookmarks to slicer and add those bookmarks in action property of buttons. In Power BI Embed you can apply `buttonClick` event to the button and set the state of slicer but that event will be triggered for all the buttons in the report. Instead of having 4 buttons you can use only one button and set slicer state according to the number of times the button is clicked. To change the state of a slicer on clicking a button in an Embed report, Please find the below code snippet:

1. Set the Filter config:

```js
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#advanced",
    target: {
        table: "Table_Name",
        column: "Column_Name"
    },
    filterType: models.FilterType.Advanced,
    logicalOperator: "And",
    conditions: [
        // Add condition here as per your requirement
    ]
};
```

2. Get the current active page:

```js
const pages = await report.getPages();

    // Retrieve the active page.
let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
    return page.isActive;
})[0];
```

3. Get all the visuals:

```js
const visuals = await page.getVisuals();
```

4. Find the slicer:

```js
let slicer = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
        return visual.type === "slicer" && visual.name === "Visual_Name";
    })[0];
```

5. Add the button click event and set the state of slicer:

```js
report.on("buttonClicked", function (event) {
        slicer.setSlicerState({ filters: [filter] });
    });
```

Pleaser find references here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#buttonclicked
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers#set-slicer-state

Answer (score 0):

Make 4 copy of slicer and select different value in each slicer. Now select the Bookmark and selection pane from ribbon and hide all 3 slicer and keep one visible. And then select the property of the button and in Action , choose Bookmark and name of bookmark created above.

Same thing you need to do for other 3 buttons. Each time selecting a new slicer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for 4 copies of the slicer. Just change the slicer options, save it into bookmarks and connect each button to the bookmark depicting the slicer option you want to depict.